# Sum of elements in matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
{
  {2, 3},
  {4, 1, 6},
  {7, 8}
}
```

And I need to pick one element from each array and return the sum. For example:

- `2 + 4 + 7 = 13`
- `2 + 1 + 7 = 10`
- `2 + 6 + 7 = 15`
- `2 + 4 + 8 = 14`
- `2 + 1 + 8 = 11`
- `2 + 6 + 8 = 16`
- `3 + 4 + 7 = 14`
- `3 + 1 + 7 = 11`
- `3 + 6 + 7 = 16`
- `3 + 4 + 8 = 15`
- `3 + 1 + 8 = 12`
- `3 + 6 + 8 = 17`

I'm novice in algorithms and I don't know how to start to solve problem. What type of algorithms I need to use?

Comment: Where exactly does the "max" part come in?

Comment: @user2357112 ups, I remove `max` from question.

Comment: As you can see from your explanation, you need to loop through all the arrays (it's not really a matrix) and calculate the sums.

Comment: You have a jagged array, not a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind representing your (jagged) matrix as an array of arrays in JSON, then the following (a) answers the question, and (b) might suggest an approach in other programming languages.  For the sake of (b), I've appended the definition of "combinations", which is provided as a builtin in jq 1.5.

See https://stedolan.github.io/jq for more about jq.

The program:

```
combinations | add
```

Since the program is so simple, it can readily be invoked on the command line.  Here is a transcript (where the $ signifies a Mac or Linux or similar environment):

```
$ jq 'combinations|add'
[[2, 3],
 [4, 1, 6],
 [7, 8] ]
```

Output:

```
13
10
15
14
11
16
14
15
11
12
16
17
```

Appendix:

```
def combinations:
  if length == 0 then []
  else .[0][] as $x
  | (.[1:] | combinations) as $y
  | [$x] +  $y
  end ;
```

Here, "combinations" produces a stream.  In some other languages, it would probably be easier to produce an array.  For example, in ruby:

```
def combinations(ary)
  if ary.length == 0
    [[]]
  else
    ans=[]
    ary[0].each { |x| combinations(ary[1..-1]).each {|y| ans << [x] + y } }
    ans
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you, it's right! But, can you show equivalent of function `combinations` on c++ or python, javascript? I don't understand `.[0][] as $x` and `| (.[1:] | combinations) as $y`.

Comment: In ruby:    def combinations(ary)
         if ary.length == 0
           [[]]
         else
           ans=[]
           ary[0].each { |x| combinations(ary[1..-1]).each {|y| ans << [x] + y } }
           ans
         end
    end
    
    combinations( [[1,2],[3,4]] )
    
    # => [[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]

Comment: @rel1x Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equivalent code in java.

```
class Sum_matrix
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
  int a[][]={
   {2, 3},
   {4, 1, 6},
   {7, 8}
  };
  int sum,i,j,k;
  for(i=0;i<a[0].length;++i)
  {
      sum=0;
      sum+=a[0][i];
      sum_fn(1,a,sum);
  }
 }
 public static void sum_fn(int i,int [][]a,int sum)
 {
     if(i==a.length)
      System.out.println(sum);
     else
     {
         for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;++j)
         {
             sum_fn(i+1,a,sum+a[i][j]);
         }         
     }   
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `R` one liner:

```
rowSums(expand.grid(list(c(2,3), c(4,1,6), c(7,8))))
```

With some explanations:

```
# first you define a list of vectors. 
# Each vector contains numbers with which you want to obtain combination.

lst = list(c(2,3), c(4,1,6), c(7,8))

# then you generate all combinations using function expand.grid
# this will return a dataframe, with each line having a different combination.

df = expand.grid(lst)

#   Var1 Var2 Var3
#1     2    4    7
#2     3    4    7
#3     2    1    7
#4     3    1    7
#5     2    6    7
#6     3    6    7
#7     2    4    8
#8     3    4    8
#9     2    1    8
#10    3    1    8
#11    2    6    8
#12    3    6    8

# Finally you just apply rowSums to have the desired result:

rowSums(df)
#[1] 13 14 10 11 15 16 14 15 11 12 16 17
```